# ls cmd not showing files and dirs in the order I need

Tags: bash, scripting, ls, timestamps

I have a mymid_LS script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -pt
```

it is supposed to list all files and dirs(not hidden) and sort them by the order of time modified.

I made my script executable:

```
chmod 755 my_midLS
```

I created 3 dirs and 2 files:

```
$>mkdir dir00 dir01 dir02
$>touch file00 file01
```

It's supposed to show files in this order:

```
$>./my_midLS
file01  file00  dir02/  dir01/  dir00/  my_midLS
```

but it shows in this order:

```
file00  file01  dir00/  dir01/  dir02/  my_midLS
```

the only problem is the files and dirs are shown in reverse...

how to fix the order of files and dirs to be shown?

Comment: If you run `stat -c'%y %n' dir00 dir01 dir02 file00 file01` (assuming you're on a GNU system), you'll probably see why. Timestamp precision may be to the nanosecond, but at least on Linux+ext4, timestamp is *set* based on an internal clock that doesn't tick every nanosecond.

Comment: See also [linux: touch date precision](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/393056)

Comment: are you on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

If you turn your short `sh` script into a `zsh` script, you can ask the `zsh` shell to order the names in the order you want:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

ls -p -fd -- *(om)
```

Here, `(om)` is a glob qualifier that changes the behavior of the preceding pattern.  `om` means "order by last-modified-time". I then call `ls -fd` with this list of names, using `-f` to stop `ls` from changing the order and `-d` to not list the contents of directories.

Instead of the `ls` command, you could also use

```
print -rC1 -- *(Nom)
```

to print the list in a single column (`-C1`). The `-r` stops `print` from interpreting backslash sequences. The `N` in the glob qualifier acts like `nullglob` in `bash`, i.e. it makes the pattern expand to nothing if there is no match (rather than generating an error).

Comment: thx but i need to use bash shell, regular shell

Comment: Kusalanda thx , it needs to be script, can i put print cmd in a file and run it?

Comment: Maybe `print -rC1 -- *(Nom)` to produce no output if there's no non-hidden file (instead of an error message that the glob has not match).

Answer (score -1):

If this is on a Linux system, then you are a victim of a Linux kernel bug.

On UNIX, file time stamps are created with the function `uniquetime()` that increments the fractions of a second every time it is used.

This grants uniqe file time stamps for distinct filesystem operations even in case that the system clock is not very fine grained.

On Linux however, tt seems to be usual to get the same time stamp for more than one filesystem operation.

When the timestamps are equal, the files are sortet alphabetically and this is what you observe.